# Trim file extension UITableView

Tags: nsstring, nsmutablearray, trim

I want to trim the file extension from text I have an `NSMutableArray` in table cells.

```
NSMutableArray *theFiles = [NSMutableArray new];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:@"/Test"];
for (NSString *s in fileList){
    [theFiles addObject:fileList];
}
cell.textLabel.text = theFiles[indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

This lists for example **"Xylophone.m4r"** I want to remove the **.m4r**.

Comment: well, the best way I have had luck with is to not use an extension at all for my file. As long as I created the file using XML method, it still reads file, even without the extension being there!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try `-[NSString stringByDeletingPathExtension]` (in NSPathUtilities.h).

Comment: You're already iterating through the array, just do something like [theFiles addObject: [s stringByDeletingPathExtension]].

Answer (score 3):

Actually, for my use, I was able to create a plist programmatically and just not use an extension and it works great! However, anothe rway to do this is:

```
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".fileextension" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have to delete path extension component:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[theFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```